# Adding second RAID controller to a motherboard with onboard RAID controller

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware, raid-controller

One of our server ASUS M4N78AM motherboard that comes with an onboard RAID controller. We have already utilised it and are running out of space.

Would it be possible to install an additional RAID controller and add more hard drives? Is that theorotically possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes, it is absolutely possible.

But no, not into the SAME RAID GROUPS.

So, you can have a Raid 5 on the mobo, and  Raid 5 on the second controller, but no hardware supported Raid 5 using discs from both.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your motherboard has physical slot(s) available, then yes, it's certainly possible.